# Future struct that prints duration until it is Ready

Tags: rust

I'm going through some exercises to learn about working with Pins. In the followinge example, I'm implementing Future for a wrapper around another Future. Calling poll on the wrapper will print the elapsed duration if the Future is Ready. I implemented this without relying on the pin_project crate.

```
struct MeasurableFuture<Fut> {
    inner_future: Fut,
    started_at: Option<std::time::Instant>,
}

impl<Fut: Future> Future for MeasurableFuture<Fut> {
    type Output = Fut::Output;

    fn poll(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> std::task::Poll<Self::Output> {
        let result;
        unsafe {
            result = self
                .as_mut()
                .map_unchecked_mut(|this| &mut this.inner_future)
                .poll(cx);
        }
        if result.is_ready() {
            if let Some(start_time) = self.started_at {
                let diff = start_time.elapsed();
                println!("duration was: {:?}", diff);
            }
        }
        result
    }
}
```

Questions around this:

1. I had to bind `self` as `mut` locally in the implementation in order to borrow it mutably. Otherwise, this would have consumed `self`, and I couldn't use `started_at` later due to the move. Is there a problem with changing the binding mode for `self`? Is there a more elegant way to get around the move that would happen?
2. Is there a cleaner way of calling `poll` on the `inner_future`?
3. Is there a better way of executing the effect of printing the duration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of on how to execute the effect of printing the duration better.

1. Use the `log` crate to log instead of `println`. At least this gives the user the option to control where and how to output the message.
2. Provide `MeasurableFuture` with a handler function that can be passed in on instantiation. The handler gets called instead of `println`. This has the advantage that code which cares gets to use the actual value and can do something useful with it.